# Is an 400+% increase in lift with distributed propulsion realistic?

Tags: aerodynamics

Is an 440% increase in lift with distributed propulsion realistic?

I understand NASA swapped out the wings on their test plane with distributed propulsion from 17psf to 45 psf.  That's a factor of 2.6, which is an increase in efficiency of 260%!!

If the original wings have a cL of: 50% classic airfoil cL max of 1.5 + 50% slotted flap cl max of 2.7. that works out a wing cL max of about 2.1

So... cL of new wings must be a cL of 2.1 x 2.6 = 5.5, or an increase in cL of about 3.4.

S0... if I start with a foil like the Selig1233, with a max cL of 2.5, a slat adds .7 plus 3.4 for distributed propulsion, I'm looking at a total cL of 6.6.

A cL of 6.6/1.5 is a 440% increase in lift.

Is this realistic?

If not, what is?

Use would be for a small ultralight, max speed about 60mph.

Comment: Efficiency in what sense? For STOL? Sure. For cruise? Probably not unless cruising slowly is part of your mission.

Comment: Also, I see that you've asked 32 questions with zero accepted answer. We would appreciate if you can accept some of these answers, many of which took a while to do.

Comment: how do you accept answers?

Comment: There is a green check mark below the votes for accepting the answer. One question can have at most one accepted answer.